# Rally simple card board app on custom field

Tags: rally

I am trying to build rally external app showing user story cards it works fine for schedule state as attribute but when I change to custom field it loads headers and spinner image comes nothing happens, here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Copyright (c) 2011 Rally Software Development Corp. All rights reserved -->
<html>
<head>
   <title>Component Example: Card Board</title>
   <meta name="Name" content="Josh Custom App" />
   <meta name="Version" content="2011.2" />
   <meta name="Vendor" content="Rally Software" />
   <script src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.26/sdk.js?loginKey=122222222222222222"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">



       function onLoad() {

           var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource(
             '1234',
             '5678',
             'false',
             'false');
           var cardboardConfig = {
               types: ["HierarchicalRequirement"],
             // attribute:  'ScheduleState',
               attribute: "c_MathState",
               fetch: "Name,FormattedID,Owner,ObjectID"
           };

           var cardboard = new rally.sdk.ui.CardBoard(cardboardConfig,             rallyDataSource);
            cardboard.display("cardboard");
       }

       rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);


   </script>
</head>
<body>

   <div id="cardboard"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [AppSDK 2.0 Cardboard](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/example/simple-board) instead, as AppSDK 1.x is deprecated.

However, in your AppSDK 1.x code above, try using: `MathState`

As your attribute, instead of: `c_MathState`. With AppSDK 1.x / WSAPI 1.x, it is not necessary to prefix your custom field names with `c_`.